# Play youtube individual player rather in a single for multiple YouTube Video

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-api

I have multiple YouTube Video on page and I want to open each YouTube Video on indivually.

My script is Pay/Run Video on single div. SO I want three video play in individual div id player. SO I taken three div with div id player.

HTML

```js
// 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
    var tag = document.createElement('script');

    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
    //    after the API code downloads.
    var player;

    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
      // This function seems to be needed, so, don't remove it from your code.
     }

    // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.mute();
    event.target.playVideo();
    }

    // Render the IFRAME once the button is clicked.
    function youtubevideo(videoIdval) {

    // "Destroy" the "player" > for allow re-create it with the new "clicked" video_id.
    if (player != null || player != undefined) {
     player.destroy();
    }

    // Build the iframe with the "clicked" video_id: 
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      width: '100%',
      videoId: videoIdval,
      playerVars: {
        'autoplay': 1,
        'playsinline': 1,
        'origin': window.location.href
      },
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady
      }
     });

     }
```

```html
           <div>
           <div id="player"></div>
           <button onclick="youtubevideo('o5x6t68xVVE')">Click me</button>
           </div>   

           <div>
           <div id="player"></div>
          <button onclick="youtubevideo('wJp-BZpVBPA')">Click me</button>
           </div>
           <div>
           <div id="player"></div>
          <button onclick="youtubevideo('sPhhZg9v9NU')">Click me</button>
           </div>
```

Comment: You should not have same id on html page.

Comment: I tried with Different ids as well. Can write code in jsfiddle with your way
           <div>
           <div id="player"></div>
           <button onclick="youtubevideo('o5x6t68xVVE')">Click me</button>
           </div>   

           <div>
           <div id="player1"></div>
          <button onclick="youtubevideo1('wJp-BZpVBPA')">Click me</button>
           </div>
           <div>
           <div id="player2"></div>
          <button onclick="youtubevideo2('sPhhZg9v9NU')">Click me</button>
           </div>

Comment: So what happened in that case?

Comment: not working and giving js error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment. Ids should not repeat in a single HTML page. Here is how you can solve the problem. You can assign unique id for each player and once button is clicked find that element with javascript and initialise the player on that element.

Please check example below.

```js
// 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
    var tag = document.createElement('script');

    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
    //    after the API code downloads.
    var player;

    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
      // This function seems to be needed, so, don't remove it from your code.
     }

    // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
      event.target.mute();
      event.target.playVideo();
    }

    // Render the IFRAME once the button is clicked.
    function youtubevideo(elem, videoIdval) {
const playerElem = elem.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];

    // "Destroy" the "player" > for allow re-create it with the new "clicked" video_id.
    if (player != null || player != undefined) {
      player.destroy();
    }

    // Build the iframe with the "clicked" video_id: 
    player = new YT.Player(playerElem, {
      width: '100%',
      videoId: videoIdval,
      playerVars: {
        'autoplay': 1,
        'playsinline': 1,
        'origin': window.location.href
      },
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady
      }
     });

     }
```

```html
           <div>
           <div id="player1"></div>
           <button onclick="youtubevideo(this, 'o5x6t68xVVE')">Click me</button>
           </div>   

           <div>
           <div id="player2"></div>
          <button onclick="youtubevideo(this, 'wJp-BZpVBPA')">Click me</button>
           </div>
           <div>
           <div id="player3"></div>
          <button onclick="youtubevideo(this, 'sPhhZg9v9NU')">Click me</button>
           </div>
```

Comment: This is working but click on second button removed first video. How could be keep running video those get click once .

Comment: Your initial code does not work like that way. You are overriding players on single player variable. You can try to create new instances on button click.

Comment: I am not getting you, Could you edit you Answered code what exactly pointing to.

Comment: You can just comment out this line: player.destroy();

Comment: You can remove that enclosing if condition altogether which is wrapping player.destory. That's not needed. Upvote and mark the solution as answer if it helped you.

Comment: How we can play sound along with Video?

Comment: There must be some settings to unmute the sound when you initialise YT.player. you can refer youtube docs for the same.